# merging tables with different structures

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two tables where I want to find the outer join based on a Ticker variable.

In Table I, I have only **one** Ticker for each entity (fund), but in table II, I may have multiple records (multiple Ticker) for each "FundID". The goal is to count the unique funds.

I want to have table III, which is the combination of both tables I and II at the fund level. If a Ticker exists in both tables, that is considered as one record in table III. If a Ticker exists in table II but not in table I, I want it in table III.

However, I don't want another Ticker from the same fund ("FundID"). In that case, we may pick one representative Ticker at random from each fund group (again, they will have the same "FundID"), and thus we won't have multiple Ticker for one specific fund.

Table 1:

| Ticker |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

Table II:

| Ticker | FundID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| AA | 1 |
| AB | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| BB | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| EB | 3 |
| EC | 3 |

Table III(combined):

| Ticker |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |

Comment: So your out put should be A B E? C AND D in table 1 only

Comment: output is A, B, C, D,E. A-D are from the Table I and we add E from table II as it is not available in table I. We ignore EB or EC as they have the same fundID as E. I dont care if we keep E or EB, or EC. just one of them should show up in table III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter `df2` for rows where for each FundID, none of their corresponding "Ticker" is in `df1['Ticket']`. Then among these FundIDs, sample one Ticker for each FundID and concatenate this to `df1`:

```
sub_df2 = df2[~df2['Ticker'].isin(df1['Ticket']).groupby(df2['FundID']).cummax()]
out = pd.concat((df1, sub_df2.groupby('FundID')['Ticker'].sample(n=1).to_frame().rename(columns={'Ticker':'Ticket'})))
```

Output:

```
  Ticket
0      A
1      B
2      C
3      D
5      E
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `merge` then pass the filter with `duplicated`

```
out = t1.merge(t2,how='outer')
out = out[~out['FundID'].duplicated() | out['FundID'].isna()]
Out[87]: 
  Ticker  FundID
0      A     1.0
1      B     2.0
2      C     NaN
3      D     NaN
7      E     3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @BENY. I am unsure why I get much lower number of records as I expect from real data. Maybe we need to add more conditions to the second  code line to capture all records.